# Why the text is not blinking as expected

Tags: html, css, text

I am trying to figure out why my text is not blinking as supposed in browsers (any browser)?
It does blink though on my Android phone...
I have this in my CSS:

```
.blink {
    animation: blink-animation 1s steps(3, start) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(3, start) infinite;
    color: red;
}
```

and this in the HTML page (it is actually a .PHP file:

```
<li><a itemprop="significantLink" href="/blog/complaints" title="Report a phone number"><div class="circle"><h2>FREE<br>complaint</h2><div class="blink">Report harassing<br>phone calls<br>and scam</div></div></a></li>
```

and here the web page for reference - https://reverd.com/index.php - text in the first circle (left) should blink...

I tried 4 different browsers Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera - none of them showed blinking text.
the text blinks on my Android phone though...

Comment: You have the `.blink` rule wrapped into `@media only screen and (max-width:600px)`

Comment: You might be right. Just to clarify where is it wrapped? - Do you mean the rule is wrapped in the .css ? - pls. clarify. Thx.

Comment: You put that `.blink` rule _into_ `@media only screen and (max-width:600px) { ... }`, so it doesn't apply on screens wider than 600px.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Now the blinking text is working on all browsers & the phone. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code i hope solve your issue.

```css
.blink {
        animation: blink-animation 1s steps(3, start) infinite;
        -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(3, start) infinite;
      }
      @keyframes blink-animation {
        to {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes blink-animation {
        to {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
      }
```

```html
<li><a itemprop="significantLink" href="/blog/complaints" title="Report a phone number"><div class="circle"><h2>FREE<br>complaint</h2><div class="blink">Report harassing<br>phone calls<br>and scam</div></div></a></li>
```

Comment: Replaced the code in the css - no difference...